# I can be quite bright but I'm never right. Can you guess who I am?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I can be quite bright but I'm never right.
I support you in peace and protect you in fight.

I'm seldom alone and when I am, there's no use.
Even when you select me, another you choose.

You never ask how I'm doing, even when I'm blue.
I might be unhealthy but I can't catch a flu.

Sometimes I'm in transit and sometimes home I'll stay.
Sometimes you can see a person who for me will pray.

If you don't have me at all, you're poor not having a dime
Or you might simply have fallen as a victim of crime.

I can hurt you and wound you and even make you bleed.
Regardless of your pain, I'm something you still need.

I might be unwanted but also an object of desire.
I could be damaged by earth, water and fire.

I could be expensive or cheap or even free.
When people look at you, they often see me.

You'll be both arrogant and humble if I'm put on your head.
I often bear a name that someone else before me had.

**What am I?**

---

## Hints

- > We're looking for a common everyday object.
- > It's not anything abstract as "love" or "energy".
- > It's not symbolic as "the letter A" or "peace sign".

Comment: *I could be damaged by earth, water and fire.* does the answer related to anime / games?

Comment: I'm trying to think of synonyms for money but I'm thinking it might be regional.

Comment: Are you a diet for some legendary species?

Comment: @Alex No anime, no game, no legendary anything. Well, one type of it was at one point called legendary but that's **veeery** misleading. So no, nothing extraordinary. Remember - you need it too and I'm assuming you're not a legendary species nor a cartoon from manga, hehe.

Comment: @Kingrames I can see why you're thinking of money. But no - the reference to poor and/or victim of a crime is more far-fetched than the direct possession of the money. You need to combine all the hints.

Comment: I've added a much more far fetched answer...

Comment: A clue? Or hint?

Comment: @DrXorile I'll gladly post a hint. Are there any rules or conventions on how long time I should wait before doing so? Any suggestions on how much to post as a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it:

> A left shoe

I can be quite bright but I'm never right.
I support you in peace and protect you in fight.

> Shoes can be flashy.  Left shoe isn't right.  Supports you, and you can kick people with it

I'm seldom alone and when I am, there's no use.
Even when you select me, another you choose.

> Mostly useful in pairs

You never ask how I'm doing, even when I'm blue.
I might be unhealthy but I can't catch a flu.

> Shoes can be blue, but you still don't inquire about their health.  And a shoe can be nasty!

Sometimes I'm in transit and sometimes home I'll stay.
Sometimes you can see a person who for me will pray.

> You went with them or leave them behind.  Some people are desperate for particular examples.

If you don't have me at all, you're poor not having a dime
Or you might simply have fallen as a victim of crime.

> Even very poor people have shoes.

I can hurt you and wound you and even make you bleed.
Regardless of your pain, I'm something you still need.

> Shoes hurt you, and can make you bleed, but you still need them.

I might be unwanted but also an object of desire.
I could be damaged by earth, water and fire.

> Unwanted old shoe vs designer shoe.  Some are susceptible to damage from mud, water or fire.

I could be expensive or cheap or even free.
When people look at you, they often see me.

> Range of shoes available.  Put your best foot forward.  Shoes are often noticed.

You'll be both arrogant and humble if I'm put on your head.
I often bear a name that someone else before me had.

> Shoes sometimes have the name of their designer.  A shoe on the head could be a sign of madness or a very eccentric hat such as an aristocrat might wear.

Comment: Google "*shoe on head*" for references. It's an ancient symbol of humbleness among Native Indians. The same (indeed weird) placement has also been used to arrogantly make fun of underprivileged dancers (in sex industry). Apart from that - you've got it, mate. Congratulations! Since this was my first riddle ever (of this descriptive kind, that is) and since I'm not a native speaker, I'd welcome any feed-back you (or anybody else) might offer on how to improve. I had awesomely much fun creating the riddle, I must admit.

Comment: I really enjoyed it, even if it took me three goes!

Comment: I'll add a reference to Life of Brian in for 'Sometimes you can see a person who for me will pray.'

Comment: I feel like the "victim of a crime" part is a reference to something. I'm not too familiar with thief legends and movie culture though. Is there a universe where some famous robber was taking the shoes of their victims? EDIT: Oh wait. That's right, shoes are often inspected in obduction after a murder, and therein of course taken off of the victim.

Comment: @yunzen I don't remember what that reference would be. Help me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess the obvious answer, even though I suspect it's wrong:

> Paper money

I can be quite bright but I'm never right.
I support you in peace and protect you in fight.

> Useful in many circumstances

I'm seldom alone and when I am, there's no use.
Even when you select me, another you choose.

> Kept in a wallet.  When you select me, it's to pay and get something else

You never ask how I'm doing, even when I'm blue.
I might be unhealthy but I can't catch a flu.

> No relationship with your money, and spending can be unhealthy

Sometimes I'm in transit and sometimes home I'll stay.
Sometimes you can see a person who for me will pray.

> Sometimes you forget your wallet.  Plenty of people pray for it.

If you don't have me at all, you're poor not having a dime
Or you might simply have fallen as a victim of crime.

> Stolen or poor if you don't have it.

I can hurt you and wound you and even make you bleed.
Regardless of your pain, I'm something you still need.

> Paper cut!

I might be unwanted but also an object of desire.
I could be damaged by earth, water and fire.

> Easily damaged.  Many people want to go cash free

I could be expensive or cheap or even free.
When people look at you, they often see me.

> Different denominations.  People often figure out how to get you to pay, and are not interested in you otherwise.

You'll be both arrogant and humble if I'm put on your head.
I often bear a name that someone else before me had.

> Notes often have famous people on them.  You look stupid with money (literally) on your head, but you might be arrogant if people pour money on your head (a euphemism for pay well).

Comment: You're awesomely thorough. The only thing you didn't address was the blue-state (which **could** be the color of some bills, if I'm to follow your guess) plus you're a bit vague on the first section (without contradicting it). The remark about never being right should be taken literally. Plus money is kind of never free.

Comment: You could buy the fake ones or just make your own though

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is even more far fetched:

> A hook used as a prosthetic left arm

I can be quite bright but I'm never right.
I support you in peace and protect you in fight.

> Can be shiny, but it's still for the left (not the right).  Used both for peace, and can be an effective defensive weapon

I'm seldom alone and when I am, there's no use.
Even when you select me, another you choose.

> Normally you've got a right arm.  When you use your arm it's normally to pick up something else.

You never ask how I'm doing, even when I'm blue.
I might be unhealthy but I can't catch a flu.

> You don't talk to your prosthetic, even if it's blue.  It could rust or weaken, but it's not the flu.

Sometimes I'm in transit and sometimes home I'll stay.
Sometimes you can see a person who for me will pray.

> You don't always wear me.  Could be posted ahead to avoid having to take it through airport security.  If someone doesn't have one, but is missing an arm, they might ask for one.

If you don't have me at all, you're poor not having a dime
Or you might simply have fallen as a victim of crime.

> A prosthetic might be one of the first things people get, unless someone's stolen it from you.

I can hurt you and wound you and even make you bleed.
Regardless of your pain, I'm something you still need.

> Hooks could be dangerous, but still useful.

I might be unwanted but also an object of desire.
I could be damaged by earth, water and fire.

> Presumably people would prefer not to need a hook, but they need it anyway.  It's not impervious to damage.

I could be expensive or cheap or even free.
When people look at you, they often see me.

> Various levels of hook exist, from ones made from scrap to fancy ones.  But regardless, when people see you, it's still quite obvious that you wear a hook.

You'll be both arrogant and humble if I'm put on your head.
I often bear a name that someone else before me had.

> Okay, this answer seems to fall apart now...  I didn't have much hope anyway.

Comment: Very good. But if you only have one of those, it's still not useless. In fact it's quite useful then. Also, remark about being poor applies to most people, including you. I'm assuming that you don't have a prosthetic arm but you're not poor because of that. You're just not disabled. Also, most of such hooks is definitely water resistant, can be dirty and in many cases withstand fire. So, in conclusion, nope - wrong answer. Very well put, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess.

I can be quite bright but I'm never right.
I support you in peace and protect you in fight.

> Energy

I'm seldom alone and when I am, there's no use.
Even when you select me, another you choose.

> Scissor(s) blade

You never ask how I'm doing, even when I'm blue.
I might be unhealthy but I can't catch a flu.

> Sky or River

Sometimes I'm in transit and sometimes home I'll stay.
Sometimes you can see a person who for me will pray.

> (Shooting) Star

If you don't have me at all, you're poor not having a dime
Or you might simply have fallen as a victim of crime.

> Wallet or Time

I can hurt you and wound you and even make you bleed.
Regardless of your pain, I'm something you still need.

> Knife

I might be unwanted but also an object of desire.
I could be damaged by earth, water and fire.

> Skin

I could be expensive or cheap or even free.
When people look at you, they often see me.

> Smile

You'll be both arrogant and humble if I'm put on your head.
I often bear a name that someone else before me had.

> Crown or Title

What am I?

> Power

Comment: I see how you went about it. Every statement describes a property and those together are the final guess, right? Very interesting but not right. I'm considering posting a hint soon because apparently I managed to give you guys a really hard time. :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten Thank you. Awaitigng the hint.

Comment: It's already posted. Kindly, view the foundation's lower section.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Got it. Thanks for the hint to the hints..;-)